# Will `typeof window === 'object'` always be true?

Tags: javascript, browser, browserify

Assuming window isn't shadowed, will `typeof window === 'object'` always be true? Is this safe?

Context: I'm trying to export a module to the global scope using browserify and I want to include a check to see if this module is run in the browser and if it is, I want to export it to the global object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a variable to global scope, browserify exposes `global` which in the browser represents `window`.

[Per the browserify docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#compatibility) (emphasis mine)

> Additionally, if you use any of these variables, they will be defined in the bundled output in a browser-appropriate way:
>
> - `process`
> - `Buffer`
> - **`global` - top-level scope object (window)**
> - `__filename` - file path of the currently executing file
> - `__dirname` - directory path of the currently executing file

---

As far as the question being asked:

> Assuming window isn't shadowed, will typeof window === 'object' always be true?

[Yes](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.3) given that it's running in a browser environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the real `window`, defined by the runtime, it will always be an object. The [`typeof` operator (§12.5.6)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-typeof-operator) has a limited number of [return values (table 15)](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#table-35), and there's no special one for `window`. If they expand that table, it could change, but the only applicable result in ES1 through ES7 is `'object'`.

Bear in mind that Node doesn't define `window` at all (so `typeof` would be `'undefined'`) and you can shadow it, as you mention. In a browser with a standard DOM implementation, `window` will be the object defined in [§7.3](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#window) of the [DOM specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html). For JavaScript, this should be an object and I believe all browsers expose it as such.

In webpack, you would use the `output.library` property and set `output.libraryTarget` to `'var'`, then the bundle sets up the global for you. I imagine browserify has an equivalent.

Comment: Is `typeof window` guaranteed to return `"object"` though? I'm not finding any spec that says it is.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara The DOM spec says it is an object (although not in the JS sense) and the JS spec has a very strict table of `typeof` results, so I'm 99% sure that will hold true until one spec changes.

Comment: Yeah, I have little doubt it will work in practice, just wondering if it is explicitly defined to not be `"function"` or something. In ES3, built-in functions type could be `"object"`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I don't think it's ever explicitly stated, which is interesting (and a little concerning). Since `window` can't be called directly (there's nothing in the IDL for that), I can't imagine it would ever be a `'function'`, plus `'object'` is the fallback if you don't meet any other `typeof` criteria.

Comment: For practical reasons, i think i'll use browserify's `global` object as mentioned in zzzzBov to export but for the purposes of the question: Would it be safer to go with `typeof window !== 'undefined'`?

Comment: @RicoKahler unfortunately I can't find any real export feature in browserify, so I think that might be what you have to do. It's a shame they left that out, especially since webpack has that exact thing (it's super useful for working with older code).

Answer (score 2):

### The answer is: It depends.

#### Short answer:

If you're in a browser, then yes, `window` will always be an object. If you're on a JavaScript standalone engine such as Node.js, then probably no.

#### More details:

A window is one of the top-hierarchy objects on a browser. It is the parent of the whole DOM tree present inside a browser window (or tab), and the context reference where most of functions and event listeners will often run.

[image: JavaScript object hierarchy]

So in any browser that expects to work properly, there will be a `window` object. *(some side/experimental projects may have modified JavaScript engines and not implement `window`, but this is highly unlikely and definitely not the kind of thing that is going to be used by "mainstream users")*

However, when we talk about JavaScript engines running outside browsers, things get a little different. On a server-side JavaScript runtime such as Node.js, the purpose is not to work with windows/tabs, URLs and DOM tree parsing such as a browser do. So you will not have this object available and running `typeof window` will return `'undefined'` on those environments.